# What is the most modern way to log to syslog using a java.util.logging handler?

Tags: java, logging, syslog, java.util.logging

I am specifically looking for the most up to date, modern `SysLogHandler` for `java.util.logging`.

I have found a few that date back to 2001 - 2003, mostly un-supported now.

I know that `syslog` is a pretty static service, I am wondering before I write something myself, if there are any newer handler implementations that support the Java 1.5 and newer features.

I am **not** interested in any of the other logging frameworks or wrapper / proxy libraries.

I am **not** looking for SLF4J or any other alternative logging frameworks, as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311697/is-there-a-robust-java-util-logging-handler-implementation-of-syslog).

Comment: You could write some code to do it. Or use a library that can already do it. Since Java can't do it out of the box.

Comment: I know you're not looking for SLF4J, but I still heartily recommend it even if you'll be using util-logging underneath.

Comment: write it yourself, probably it'd have less time than the discussion here. I know, if I need a handler I just write it myself. java.util.logging was practically unchanged in java5, in 6_18 they made some weak reference to the loggers.

Comment: Eventually, there will be a syslog writer for Tinylog: https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog/issues/156

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I met same problem - I was need a Syslog extension class for ***java.util.logging.Handler***

After searching in Internet without any success, I ended up creating my own implementation - http://code.google.com/p/agafua-syslog/ with support of UDP and TCP protocols. I use it in production project.

Comment: For use with tomcat it should be installed to `$CATALINA_HOME/endorsed`.

Comment: Due to a deprecation of Google Code project migrated to http://rusv.github.io/agafua-syslog/

Answer (score 2):

In an old job, I used the [Syslog4j](http://syslog4j.org/) library and wired up a custom Log4j-appender for it, so you can probably do something similar by implementing a custom `java.util.logging.Handler` that passes messages along.

Comment: syslog4j link seems to be broken :-(

Answer (score 1):

Syslog (at least on Linux) listens on a UDP port for input (514/udp by default).

So implement a **Handler** which sends the formatted messages to this port.  I used the existing **SocketHandler** for reference, and implemented an alterative around a **DatagramSocket**.  Mine came to about 200 lines all-in.