# how sink data to syslog using apache flume

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

is it possible to sink data from apache flume to syslog? I am currently checking from official documention, but seems there is no sink connector to Syslog available at presence. I am thnking using logstash as replacement because it supports both source and sink to syslog. However, the downside is that it is not distributed and scalable.

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you own custom sink for Syslog, if you know any Syslog API for Java. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206936/what-is-the-most-modern-way-to-log-to-syslog-using-a-java-util-logging-handler) question at StackoverFlow itslef coulf help you.

Regrding custom sink creation, it is not very complex. You have to extend the [`AbstractSink`](https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.7.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/sink/AbstractSink.html) class, and to implement the [`Configurable`](https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.7.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/conf/Configurable.html) interface. This basically means to override the `public Status process()` and `public void configure(Context context)` methods, respectively.